# Convertir una cadena a un Objeto JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo un json y dentro de ese json hay una key que tiene otro json en una cadena y no siempre sera la misma como en el ejemplo,La `key valorres` puede tener ese json en cadena o puede tener otro, no siempre sera la misma cadena ni las mismas key pueden ser varias, diferentes nombres o mas de las presentes en esa cadena JSON

Como podria convertir ese json dentro de valores a un objeto en mi getter ?

Como esta actualmente.

```
{
    "monto": "321321",
    "valores": "{"mm":"05","mont":"1234560000","id":"1","hrg":"H10000","np":"1"}",
    "valance": 0
}
```

Como deberia quedar.

```
{
   "monto":"321321",
   "valores":{
      "mm":"05",
      "mont":"1234560000",
      "id":"1",
      "hrg":"H10000",
      "np":"1"
   },
   "valance":0
}
```

Lo intento asi:

```
@JsonGetter ("valores")
public Object getValores() {
  Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put(getKey(),valores);
  return map;
}

retorna asi

{
    "id": 16,
    "valores": {
        "formato": " {\"mm\":\"05\",\"mont\":\"1234560000\",\"id\":\"1\",\"hrg\":\"H10000\",\"np\":\"1\"} "
    },
    "valance": 0
}
```

Comment: Podrías agregar qué hace el método `getKey()`  dentro de `getValores()` ?

Comment: Es otro get que tiene un nombre de otra key por ejemplo: formato, nombre, parametros: solo es una llave mas una cadena de un nombre y ya nada mas